# How to locate dynamic values in Tableau dashboard using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, tableau-api

I have been testing Tableau dashboard manually and am facing issues - time consuming and frequent data change. Can anyone help me in locating the dynamic values displayed in the trend lines using xpath or any other method used in selenium with python

Comment: Anyone please answer me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.